# Why is the if statement in my function not working?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
def userpoints(userPoint,plus,minus):
    
    userPoint = userPoint + plus
    userPoint = userPoint - minus
    return userPoint

userPoints = 20

sumdiceroll = 7

def positivepoints(sumdiceroll,userPoints):
            
    if sumdiceroll == 7:
                
        userPoints = userPoints + 1
        
        return userPoints
    
for i in range(2):
    
    positivepoints(sumdiceroll, 1)

    print(userPoints)
```

I want to know why the if statement in the function is not working. If the if statement in my positive points function was working, variable userPoints would be 22, not 20. When I execute the code, userPoints stays 20. I'm on python 3.8 by the way. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make sure the code is a proper [mre], one that we can copy-paste and try ourselves without any editing or  fixing.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the (excellent) Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) or your text-books or tutorials, and see what these resource tell you about variables and variable *scope*.

Comment: My bad for any inconvenience. First time doing this.

Comment: You're probably confusing yourself by using the same name (userPoints) for both local and global variable names

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you call

```
positivepoints(sumdiceroll, 1)
```

without assigning it to anything, so the variable `userPoints` is never altered outside of the scope of the local variable (also named `userPoints`) inside the function definition.

Try this

```
userPoints = positivepoints(sumdiceroll, 1)
```

though this will only alter `userPoints` once as you are passing the value 1 each time,

instead you could try this:

```
userPoints = 20
for i in range(2):
    
    userPoints = positivepoints(sumdiceroll, userPoints)

    print(userPoints)
```

Comment: Damn, it was that simple..... What a humbling experience. I appreciate you for answering my question Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead assigning the value you can directly print.

```
print(positivepoints(sumdiceroll, 1))
```